Cannot validate image and pdf file with FormValidation
I am using formvalidation.io to validate my form.
but I have a problem in validating image files and pdf files in one input.
try changing it here

fields: {
                fileupload: {
                    validators: {
                        file: {
                            extension: 'jpeg,jpg,png,pdf',
                            type: 'image/jpeg, image/png, application/pdf',
                            maxSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024, // 5 MB
                            message: 'The selected file is not valid, it should be (jpeg,jpg,png,pdf) and 5 MB at maximum.'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

with a format like that.
it can only upload jpg files, am I doing something wrong ?


fields: {
                fileupload: {
                    validators: {
                        file: {
                            extension: 'png,jpg,jpeg,pdf',
                            type: 'image/png,image/jpeg,application/pdf,',
                            maxSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024, // 5 MB
                            message: 'The selected file is not valid, it should be (png,jpg,jpeg,pdf) and 5 MB at maximum.'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

I think the problem is space after comma, if no space after comma it works
